# Vertically Align Image with Text Fails

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<a href="{% url 'selectteams' '0' '0'  %}" style="font-size: 20px" class="btn btn-default btn-block .btn-lg">
   <span style="vertical-align: middle;text-align: initial;margin: auto auto auto 0;">
     <img  height="42" width="42" src="/static/team_selection.svg" alt="Team Selection"/>
   <span>
   <span style="vertical-align: middle;text-align: initial;margin: auto auto auto 0;">TEAM SELECTION</span>
</a>
```

Which produces:

[image]

Whatever I attempt with the style I just can't seem vertically align the text with the image. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what you want it to look like? It appears to me that both elements are vertically centered in their parent element, so the problem may be that your image dimensions are such that centering won't give the alignment you want.

Comment: If you look closely, it is vertically aligned in the center. It gives the illusion of **not** being aligned properly because you have a bottom-heavy looking image.

Comment: Please create a code snipet to re-produce your problem

Comment: I will attempt a code snippet now :)

Comment: Terry, I think you may be right, due to the wires hanging down.

Comment: Terry was right!   Sorry all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have used flex , here is the demo, try with below snippet

```css
.anchor {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: flex;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    width: 200px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius:4px;
}
.anchor img {
    max-width: 50px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="anchor">
 <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/home-icon.png" alt="img" />
 <span>Team selection</span>
</a>
```

Comment: This is a lot cleaner than the way I was doing it.  Thank you.